# Summation notation for statistical mechanics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, notation

I was taking a look to a book of statistical mechanics, many equations show something as follows:
$$ Q(K,N) = \sum_{s_{1},s_{2},...,s_{N}=\pm 1}[ e^{K(...+s_1s_2+s_2s_3+s_3s_4...)} ]\tag{1}$$
then they partition the sum as follows
$$ Q(K,N) = \sum_{s_{1},s_{2},...,s_{N}}e^{K(s_1s_2+s_2s_3)}e^{K(s_3s_4+s_4s_5)} ... \tag{2}$$
After summing over even numbered S's
$$Q(K,N) = \sum_{s_{odd}} (e^{K(s_1+s_3)}+e^{-K(s_1+s_2)})(e^{K(s_3+s_5)}+e^{-K(s_3+s_5)})\tag{3}...$$
How can I interpret this summation with many lower indices.

Comment: Just imagine a separate $\Sigma$ for each $s_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just show an example for two indices, the generalization should be straightforward.
$$
\sum_{i,j=1,2} X_{i,j} = \sum_{i=1}^2\sum_{j=1}^2 X_{i,j} = \sum_{i=1}^2(X_{i,1}+X_{i,2})
 = X_{1,1}+X_{2,1}+X_{1,2}+X_{2,2}\,.$$